# result of policy based authorization with requirements on failure

Tags: asp.net-core

We are using policy based authorization with requirements like so:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "IsUser")]
```

When authorization fails we just get a white page with status 200.
How can we control what happens if authorization fails in ASP.NET core.
We would like something like forbidden.

Comment: Please provide more info, like how did you config in your startup?

Answer (score 0):

Note that for authorization to work in asp.net core, your authentication mechanism should be configured correctly. [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2) : "authorization requires an authentication mechanism".

It is not clear whether you are using your own code for authentication or using an asp.net core provided service (Cookie authentication / Identity / etc). Several schemes and [relevant code can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

To answer your question, you need to configure the authentication options - for example the "LoginPath". This path would correspond to the "page" that would be used to redirect to when an Authorization fails.

One example (while using Cookie based authentication) is below:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie(o => {
                o.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            });
```

In the above example (code added to the "ConfigureServices" method), Cookie based authentication is added. Default authentication and Default "Challenge" schemes are set. Further the "LoginPath" option is set for the Cookie authentication option.

Hope this helps.